# Indexer as part of the interface in C#

Tags: c#, interface, indexer

In C#, what's the syntax for declaring an indexer as part of an interface? Is it still **this[ ]**? Something feels odd about using the **this** keyword in an interface.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
public interface IYourList<T>
    {
        T this[int index] { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

It is - it's pretty odd syntax at other times if you ask me! But it works. You have to declare the `get;` and/or `set;` parts of it with no definition, just a semi-colon, exactly like ordinary properties in an interface.

Answer (score 4):

I know what you mean but, yes, **this** is correct. Here are [the docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tkyhsw31.aspx).