# Interface that Entails the Implementation of Indexer

Tags: c#

I am looking for a framework-defined interface that declares indexer. In other words, I am looking for something [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1223490/indexer-as-part-of-the-interface-in-c/1223503#1223503):

```
public interface IYourList<T>
{
    T this[int index] { get; set; }
}
```

I just wonder whether .Net framework contains such interface? If yes, what is it called?

You might ask why I can't just create the interface myself. Well, I could have. But if .Net framework already has that why should I reinvent the wheel?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you're looking for [IList<T>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ewthkb10.aspx).

Sample pasted **from the MSDN site**:

```
T this[
    int index
] { get; set; }
```

**EDIT MORE:**

This is the entire class I just Reflected to show you exactly how the interface is described in the framework:

```
[TypeDependency("System.SZArrayHelper")]
public interface IList<T> : ICollection<T>, IEnumerable<T>, IEnumerable
{
    // Methods
    int IndexOf(T item);
    void Insert(int index, T item);
    void RemoveAt(int index);

    // Properties
    T this[int index] { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: No, `IList<T>` does not have  `T this[int index] { get; set; }` as its member

Comment: @Codeslueth - Fair play, what a comeback! :)

Comment: I just double checked via Reflector... Codeslueth is correct.

Comment: Where the hell did all my rep go? Now that I'm below 1k I can't even see which post I was downvoted so much on :(

Comment: So, does that mean there is no way to write generic code working for all types which support indexers ?

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of such an interface in the BCL.

Answer (score 0):

There is no interface that only implements an indexer (generic or otherwise).

The closest you can get is use some of the collection interfaces, such as IList.